# How can I change the auto-hibernate settings on a AWS Cloud9 EC2 Instance

Tags: cloud9, hibernation

While setting up the AWS Cloud9 EC2 instance, I selected 30 mins for auto-hibernation. I would like to change this to X time/Never. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Now you can login to the Cloud9 and change the value as per your need:

`vim ~/.c9/autoshutdown-configuration`

e.g SHUTDOWN_TIME=120